# Trying to display posts in wordpress but getting the pages as output

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to display the posts on my front page of the `roots theme`'s `base.php` file.

I have added the loop as

```
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php
            echo '<h2>';
            the_title();
            echo '</h2>';
            the_content( 'Read the full post »' ); ?>
<?php endwhile;?>
```

However, this keeps displaying just the content and title from the first page.

How do i get  it to display the posts?  I have set the number of posts as 3 under settings -> reading .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (have_posts()) : $count = 0;            
while (have_posts()) : the_post(); $count++;
      echo '<h2>';
      the_title(); 
      echo '</h2>';
      the_content( 'Read the full post »' ); 
endwhile;
```

endif;

Comment: This still displays the content from the pages and not posts

Comment: you only want to display posts ?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I was using the `roots` theme. Inside this theme there is the `base.php` file which needed the line

```
<?php include roots_template_path()?>
```

The absence of this line was not allowing it to pick up the correct templates.